# Getting tag name throw error ie browser using .prop() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

In my validation, i am looping and spliting the element handling by it's type. when i call this function:

```
var tagName = $(element).prop('type').toUpperCase();
```

works fine all browsers apart from ie.

in IE  how to get the type of element?

the error is here:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'toUpperCase' of undefined or null reference
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/68kv5/24/)

Comment: Have you tried using..? `$(element).prop('tagName')`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy `tagName` isn't a standard property, why would you use that to get the `type`?

Comment: that means `$(element).prop('type')` is undefined

Comment: its because your element not exists

Comment: I am finding the type, reason because i can directly find whether this is text box or radio button or something else...

Comment: what is `element`? Please try to post relevant code to help you better

Comment: @Barmar attr('type') - not working even with chrome. ie too

Comment: @typist, element nothing but looping the form. individual element!

Comment: But if it is non-input type element, it will not have `type` attribute causing `$(element).prop('type')` to not exist (undefined)

Comment: Post your `form` html code to help you.

Comment: @Typist here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/68kv5/24/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55910/discussion-between-3gwebtrain-and-typist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery in this instance is like hitting a thumbtack with a sledge hammer. If you want the value of the `type` property on the element, just access the `type` property on the element:

```
var tagName = element.type;
```

Easy peasy, rice and cheesy.